# Appending Queries using Powerquery/M in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a series of about 70 queries in an Excel workbook, I want to append them into one output table.

Simple editor freezes, leaving me with the 'Advanced Editor' option.

I have tried:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table110"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Source", type any}, {"Sender", type any}, {"Subject", type any}, {"Date", type any}, {"Body", type any}}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null})))
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Blank Rows",#"A A",B,C,#"D D",E})
in
    #"Appended Query"
```

*(Shortened Table.Combine line for clarity)*

The editor brings back 'Token Comma expected' for this and highlights the `#"Appended Query"` in line:

```
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Blank Rows",#"A A",B,C,#"D D",E})
```

Can anyone see/help explain this error?

Comment: Try adding a comma at the end of the line before the #"Appended Query" line.

Comment: Thank you Marc!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma is missing at the end of step #"Removed Blank Rows".

Comment: Argh! Thank you so much